# javascript snippet works on console, but not on page

Tags: javascript

I'd like to use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) and have included the moment.js in the head portion of the html. I am using [foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) framework and loading the js like so:

```
<script src="/static/js/moment.js"></script>
<script src="/theme/javascripts/vendor/custom.modernizr.js"></script>
<script src="/theme/javascripts/foundation.min.js"></script>
```

In my page that is being served, I call this:

```
<script>moment("20130420", "YYYYMMDD").fromNow();</script>
```

Nothing shows up. It is blank.

However, when I go to the console and type `moment("20130420", "YYYYMMDD").fromNow();`, I get `in a month` in the console which is correct.

What can be going on such that the date does not show up on the page, but works on the console?

Comment: It is probably returning something. But you aren't doing anything with it as far as I can tell. You aren't logging it in the console and not pushing it to the screen

Comment: JavaScript doesn't work like PHP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do something with the result:

```
<script>document.writeln(moment("20130420", "YYYYMMDD").fromNow());</script>
```